# Flink Dashboard UI Tasks hard limit

Tags: apache-flink

Flink Dashboard UI seems to show tasks having a hard limit for Tasks column around 18000 on a Ubuntu Linux box.
I kept increasing the number of slots per task manager to 15 and number of slots increased to 705 but the slots to tasks
stayed at around 18000. Below 18000 tasks, the Flink Job is able to start up.
Even though I increased the number of slots, it still works when 312 slots are being used.

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 15

What knob can I tune to increase the number of Tasks ?

Pls find attached the Flink Dashboard UI.

TIA,
[image: Flink Dashboard UI]

Comment: Can you share the command you're using to start job? You could define tasks and slots in the command, also parallelism can be defined in Flink Job's code.

Comment: @AnuragAnand How do you define tasks in the command ? I have defined max parallelism via args to the program.

Comment: ~/flink-1.8.0/bin/flink run -p 12 -yn 4 -yqu default -ys 3 -c "path_to_class" ~/my.jar --parallelism 12
There are several more arguments, not added here.

Comment: @AnuragAnand Doesn't have anything for tasks.

Comment: Increasing network memory buffers seems to increase tasks slightly